# understanding Poincare conjecture

Tags: general-topology

I was reading a Wikipedia article on Poincaré conjecture and found out

that it basically says that if each loop in the space can be 
continuously tightened to a point then the space is topologically 
equivalent to a sphere. But what puzzles me is that you can deform any 
sphere into a box (therefore it would seem that they are topologically 
identical) and yet you cannot tighten a knot around the box into a point

(at least not continuously).

Comment: Yes you can! Any loop on a box can be dragged over the sides and eventually shrunk to a point.

Comment: Stupid me. Now I can see it. I was looking only on the case where you go over the entire box.

Comment: To make the statement about the sphere and box a little more precise: If two space $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic, then they have the same fundamental group (you can think of this informally as the set of different 'kinds' of loops you can have in the space).